# ObjectBox Database & Internal Storage in Flutter Stops Working When You Update The App

Tags: flutter, objectbox, internal-storage, flutter-objectbox

I have a flutter application using ObjectBox as the database that's being stored in internal storage, and I ran into the problem of when I update the application version (for example version 1.0.0) to a new version (1.0.1) the data is lost. I'm not too sure if it's the internal storage at fault or the database.

I expect that regardless of updating the application the data stays persistent.

Comment: Is it possible that in your app the database path changes with the app version? Otherwise changing the version number should not have any effect on ObjectBox. If you can reproduce this with a small example project, we welcome an issue at https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart!

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox That is my suspicion as well, When I do find the time I'll make sure to recreate the issue in a smaller project. Thanks for reaching out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I noticed I was saving the absolute path of the content in the database and upon updating the application the absolute path became obsolete therefore I resulted to saving the name of the content and then getting the internal storage then appending the two IT WORKS JUST FINE!

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify the schema at all (rename/change field types)?  If so, your new schema will not match with the old.  You'd need to go back and follow the information here:
https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/data-model-updates

Comment: No I did not edit the schema, the update has no connection to the database, for example if I make UI changes and push an update to TestFlight or PlayStore, that's when I'm encountering the problem